# Sharepoint 2013 file move with drag & drop not working

Tags: drag-and-drop

I created a new folder and intended to move a file (or more files) from the root of Shared Documents to the new folder.

It does not matter if I use *Firefox 44, Microsoft Edge*, or *Internet Explorer 11*, I can only select the objects and no drag icon appeared.

If I select 1 item, the drag icon appears (in Edge), but it does nothing when I drop.

This is what I see:

[image]

How should I make this "feature" work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a **key element** in that drag and drop that should be emphasized.

You should drag the ***ICON***, and not the document itself. Using the document *icons*, the moving can be done.

Answer (score 1):

You could always open the document library with explorer, from here you can drag and drop any document to a folder. (You have to use Internet Explorer.)

[image]

Edit:

However, on your picture it looks like you selected on of the checkboxes and just highlighed the other document... Check the checkbox on every document that you wanna move and drag them to the folder.

Comment: According to this tutorial, I can move multiple files with drag into a folder that is on the same level (or they are wrong): http://www.learningsharepoint.com/2012/12/16/how-to-move-documents-into-a-folder-in-sharepoint-2013/

Comment: Internet Explorer 11. What were you using?

Comment: I tried every browser, none of them worked :( When I hold the left mouse button, only the text gets selected, no drag happens.